# Really destroy acts_as_paranoid objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem with with acts_as_paranoid objects. Now i want to really destroy the object but i cant find an easy way.

I dont like to use hard coded SQL for this problem.

Somebody knows a quick nice solution?

UPDATE

I came up with the following solution. I dont like this that much but it works....

```
# Use this function wisely
def really_destroy
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("DELETE FROM user_widgets WHERE id = #{self.id}")
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a bang to the `destroy` method.

```
def really_destroy
  self.destroy!
end
```

Comment: Is it serious that easy? :D. I will check it tomorrow! Thanks for your answer

Comment: That easy. See documentation here: https://github.com/technoweenie/acts_as_paranoid/blob/master/lib/caboose/acts/paranoid.rb#L46

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to destroy the already "soft deleted" i.e. whose "deleted_at" is already set,
Just again destroy , Means two times destroy can destroy permanent deletes a record.